# Ambiguity of an equality of two limits

Tags: calculus, limits

It is often asked to prove an equality about two limits, say, $\lim_{x\to a}f\left(x\right)=\lim_{x\to a}g\left(x\right)$.
But I'm confused by the interpretation of the equality, because it
seems that it has two interpretations:

1. $f$ approaches $\lim_{x\to a}g\left(x\right)$ as $x$ approaches $a$, or
2. $g$ approaches $\lim_{x\to a}f\left(x\right)$ as $x$ approaches $a$.

But many proofs of this kind of equalities seem to only prove either
one of them. For instance, if the interpretation (2) is chosen, the
proof is like: let $l=\lim_{x\to a}f\left(x\right)$ then prove $l=\lim_{x\to a}g\left(x\right)$.
Why is it possible that the proof can be valid considering only one
of the interpretations?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is that

$$A=B \iff B=A$$

therefore, assuming both limit exist finite, proving that $\lim_{x\to a}f\left(x\right)=\lim_{x\to a}g\left(x\right)$ by

$$\lim_{x\to a}f\left(x\right)=l \implies \lim_{x\to a}g\left(x\right)=l$$

is equivalent to prove the statement by

$$\lim_{x\to a}g\left(x\right)=l \implies \lim_{x\to a}f\left(x\right)=l$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does it mean the symmetric relation holds for "=" used to define a limit? But does it mean it is subjected to proof? To me, it doesn't seem obvious.